# Relative Layout Overlay the Components declared in the RelativeLayout Component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-relativelayout

I am very new in as a android developer and i am currently understanding the RelativeLayout but facing a smaller problem that Textview is overLapping on the Image. Here I am providing you the Image that what i want and what i am getting and also the code that much i have did. so please Help me.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstImage"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/firstImage"
        android:text="@string/menu" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Image that i want in layout.

[image]

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I'd use a LinearLayout.  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use these property

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"    
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

for text view..

check this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"    
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"     
    android:text="menu" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add two more properities of textview `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:gravity="center"`, so text will be centered inside yout TextView.

In this there might be a problem if text is too big (it will overlap the images). To avoid that you should define your layout like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash1"
  />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/secondImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash1" 
  />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/firstImage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/firstImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/secondImage"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/menu"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice, how both image views are defined before TextView. That's because those image views will be your anchor views, meaning everything else will be aligned depending on them. Your TextView is now between 2 ImageViews so no matter what text there is, it will not overlap anything.

Answer (score 1):

replace your xml file code with this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/firstImage2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstImage"
        android:text="@string/menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to graphic mode and fix the above. It is not that you have to define every thing in XML directly but you can switch to graphic mode and fix this.